# CGI.pm : include image?

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm writting Perl/CGI script with the module CGI.pm. I can return text/html, but can't include an image within it, it always display the 'alt' tag and I'm sure about the href link.

Here's my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use CGI;

my $cgi = new CGI;

print $cgi->header(-type=>'text/html'),
      $cgi->start_html(-title=>'Test Page'),
      $cgi->h1('Infos switch'),
        "This is a test.",
      $cgi->h1('Testing'), $cgi->hr, "\n",
      $cgi->img(-src=>'http://www.perl.org/simages/lcamel.gif',  
                -alt=>'Powered by Perl'), "\n\n",
      $cgi->end_html;
exit;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you're not getting the alt text. You're sending `<img>-src http://www.perl.org/simages/lcamel.gif -alt Powered by Perl`, so the image doesn't even have alt text.

The first argument of img should be a hash of attributes. The rest is taken as child elements.

```
$cgi->img({
   -src => 'http://www.perl.org/simages/lcamel.gif',  
   -alt => 'Powered by Perl',
})
```

The dashes are optional, so you could also use

```
$cgi->img({
   src => 'http://www.perl.org/simages/lcamel.gif',  
   alt => 'Powered by Perl',
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, I can display a picture :) I have now to format all my images to create my switch on the browser....

Comment: Ok srry dude, i'm not aware of the voting community, didn't know that we have to vote.